# name of windows POSIX dll

Tags: windows, dll, posix

I'm trying to create a POSIX package in dart that will give dart programmers access to the OSs POSIX API.

I have the basics working for Linux and osx.

The problem is I can't find the name of the windows dll that contains the POSIX API.

The library doesn't need to be complete (but that would obviously be better) as the Dart code can call into multiple api's to expose a full POSIX api.  I

I do have a strong preference to not require the user to download any binaries.

As mentioned below the universial C runtime seems to have at least some of the apis.
So the follow up questions  would be are the universial C runtimes now included in the core windows distribution or do they need to be installed.

Comment: NT 8.1+ systems don't support a POSIX API. The subsystem for UNIX-based Applications (SUA) was removed in Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2. Even when SFU/SUA was supported, it wasn't installed by default or even available in all editions of the OS. Microsoft abandoned the POSIX susbsytem approach in favor of WSL.

Comment: Windows support for POSIX APIs is severely limited.  The first thing that comes to mind when I hear "POSIX" in the context of Windows is [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org).  You might be able to make use of cygwin1.dll to offer more POSIX functionality on Windows than what is natively available.

Comment: I just found this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-crt?view=vs-2019 but I'm guessing that the dlls would need to be redistributed (which I'm looking to avoid).

Comment: @BrettSutton Functions like that one are exactly what I'm referring to.  Many common functions like `fcntl`, `mmap`, and `strcasecmp` are nonexistent.  If you still want to use them, they are implemented by whatever [C runtime library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019) is being used.  These days, that means the Universal C Runtime Library (UCRT).  You'll want to review the "Redistributing Visual C++ Files" link on that page.

Comment: The C runtime has a few functions with POSIX names and provides POSIX-like file descriptors for regular files and pipes (not sockets), but to call it a POSIX API would be extremely wrong. As mentioned, if you want a real POSIX API, use a third-party library such as Cygwin or MSYS2.

Comment: You reference `_access`, but how it's implemented is a good representation of the joke that is most of the C runtime's "POSIX" functions. `_access` merely checks the file attributes for the readonly flag to determine if write access is *possible* for a regular file (not a directory). It doesn't actually check file security (owner, security resource attributes, discretionary ACL, and mandatory label) to determine whether read, write, or execute *permission* is granted. It's a toy implementation carried forward from the implementation of Microsoft C for the 1980s toy operating system, MS-DOS.

Comment: So the library doesn't need to be complete (but that would obviously be better) as the Dart code can call into multiple api's to expose a full POSIX api.

Answer (score -1):

That would be `cygwin1.dll`. You need the cygwin package to get a meaningful POSIX dll. There used to be a POSIX subsystem for Windows but it was so weird that most POSIX programs didn't work, and so it rotted and Cygwin ate its lunch.

If you try to cheat your way out of this, the stuff on top of your package just won't work right. Portability is hard.

Comment: 'Portability is hard' - yes you are right on that one.